# Unable to install Twisted on CentOS server

Tags: python, linux

I've been searching the web for ways to solve this issue but nothing works.
I have a web server with CentOS 6.7 and I've successfully installed python 2.7.10 on it (it comes with version 2.6.6)

I followed up to step two in this site: https://cpaneltips.com/install-python-2-7-python-3-x-centos-cpanel/

I then installed virtualenv (using pip) and created another directory called "news"

Installed virtualenv and activated it so I have a python 2.7.10 environment. I ran "pip install scrapy"

But I have been getting this frustrating error:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy) (from versions: )

Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external Twisted to allow).
No matching distribution found for Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)

I then ran "pip install --allow-external scrapy scrapy"

still doesn't work... What am I missing?

Comment: You mixed all argument. Which module need  sub module version. Major, minor ? Use `system_package_installer install python-scrapy` for auto dependency check.

Comment: This doesn't work for CentOS. CentOS doesn't know such package!

Answer (score 2):

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted14.0.0.tar.bz2#md5=9625c094e0a18da77faa4627b98c9815 --no-check-certificate
tar -vxjf Twisted-14.0.0.tar.bz2
cd Twisted-14.0.0
python setup.py install

pip install scrapy
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's clear you need twisted, you can firstly install twisted in your virtualenv:

```
pip install twisted
```

and then install scrapy:

```
pip install scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/2a/e9e4fb2e6b2f7a75577e0614926819a472934b0b85f205ba5d5d2add54d0/Twisted-18.4.0.tar.bz2
tar -vxjf Twisted-18.4.0.tar.bz2
cd Twisted-18.4.0
python setup.py install
pip install scrapy
```